# TableView viewForHeaderInSection seperator line

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to add separator line into the  tableForHeaderInSection. Currently the code for the header section view will be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.viewWithTag(kSeparatorId) == nil {
        let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 75, y: cell.frame.height - kSeparatorHeight, width: cell.frame.width-90, height: kSeparatorHeight))
        separatorView.tag = kSeparatorId
        separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 114/256, green: 112/256, blue: 133/256, alpha: 1.0)
        separatorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        cell.addSubview(separatorView)
    }
}
```

**output:**

[[image: 1]]

**but I want this:**

[[image: 2]]

How to add line at `viewForHeaderInSection`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separator view...

```
func separatorView(width: CGFloat, inset: CGFloat, color: UIColor?) -> UIView {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 1))
    footerView.backgroundColor = color

    let insetView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: footerView.bounds.origin.x, y: footerView.bounds.origin.y, width: inset, height: 1))
    insetView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    footerView.addSubview(insetView)
    return footerView
}
```

Use the table view delegate method to set the separator view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return separatorView(width: tableView.frame.size.width, inset: tableView.separatorInset.left, color: tableView.separatorColor)
}
```

Comment: your solution show me error:
Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'UIView?'
i solved this.

Comment: What problem is that?

Comment: one line show in the top of section but i want a line in all section